# Log4J vulnerability when logging is turned off

Tags: security, log4j

Is Log4J still vulnerable when logging is turned off?

One of the programs use version 1 of Log4J. I turned it off this way -

```
logger.level: OFF
```

The app does not generate anymore logs, would it be still vulnerable?

Comment: Log4j 1.2 is not vulnerable to Log4Shell anyway.